# vim: searchin in session

Tags: vim, vi

I am new in vi.
I want to find solution to search word in all of files in my saved session.

project files - saved in session, opened in tabs
question:
how to find words in all session and show occurence in the list

regards

Comment: Try `:bufdo g/search-term`.

Answer (score 0):

`:tabdo il <search term>`

`il[ist]` lists occurrences of a search term.
`:tabdo` does a command to all tabs

Comment: nice :). and how can I go  quickly to line with pattern from this list?